# Minecraft LAN; timeout after 30 seconds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am using MultiMC 5 to host my minecraft instances. So I can see status updates on the console. Whenever my friend tries to join one specific world, I begin to lag like hell and 30 seconds later my friend gets ***connection timeout***. The console then says:

> After processing 2500 packages there is still 10.000.000 packages left.

And then slowly counts down, but then times out.

What is causing this timeout?

Comment: Does it happen if someone else logs in to the same world, what if they go to the XYZ of where your friend spawns? You said you have multiple instances, does your friend get disconnected if he connects to a different instance on the same server?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, thats why I recommend using a whitelisted server instead.
I believe the problem is that one world has to do twice the work, added with the fact that anything transparent adds lag, Minecraft is doing around 4x more work then it is meant to do on a single player world. Either that or stop playing the game on a Microwave ;)